# Undeclared Function within struct in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct, declaration

I have the following `code`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void getData() {

    static int HasDataBeenWritten;

    if (HasDataBeenWritten == 0) {

        enum flags
        {
            Country_NA = 1, 
            CountryUS = 2,
            CountryCN = 4, 
            CountryCA = 8, 
            Business_NA = 16,
            BusinessYes = 32,
            BusinessNo = 64,
            TypeOfEntityNonCommericial = 128,
            EntityPersonal = 256,
            EntityAll = 512,
        };

        struct TopDomain
        { 
            char *DomainName;
            unsigned int DataFlags:9;
        };          

        static struct TopDomain DomainData[8];

        static char DomainNameArray1[3] = {"EDU"};
        DomainData[0].DomainName = DomainNameArray1;    
        DomainData[0].DataFlags = 145;
        HasDataBeenWritten = 1;
    }

    printf("DomainData[0] : %i", (DomainData[0].DomainName));
    printf("DomainData[0] : %d", DomainData[0].DataFlags);
}
```

I want to print the array that the `*DomainName` is pointing to or even just the pointer. However, I am getting this error message

```
getData.c:48:32 error: 'DomainData' undeclared (first use in this function) (printf("DomainData[0] : %i", (DomainData[0].DomainName));
```

Do I need to declare the struct within the array or what?

Comment: Please provide the full code for a reproducible compilation error.

Comment: looks like you missed something in your copy paste, but the closing brace just before the printf statements makes me thing that you are trying to access DomainData outside the scope of its definition. But please post the full code

Comment: I added the rest of my code. Thanks for the interest!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `DomainData` (which is an array of `struct TopDomain` structures) in a place that's visible at the point of the `printf` call.

You've declared it inside a set of curly braces. The scope of the name extends from the declaration to the nearest enclosing `}`, which is just before the `printf` calls.  (Since it's `static`, its *lifetime* is the entire execution of the program, so the object still exists at that point. The problem is that its name is not visible.)

Since `DomainData` depends on the declarations of `struct TopDomain` and `enum flags`, you'll need to move those as well.

(It rarely makes much sense to declare a type inside a compound statement.)

Incidentally, your format strings are incorrect. In your first `printf`, you use `%i` for an argument of type `char*`; you want `%s` (assuming the pointer isn't `NULL`). In your second you use `%d` for an argument of type `unsigned int`; you want `%u` (or `0x%x` might be clearer in this case).

Comment: Thanks. After a long day of coding sometimes I get hung up on silly mistakes like that!

Comment: Do you think that for a data structure like this it would be better if I made the structure outside of a function?

Comment: @Alex: It rarely makes sense to define a struct inside a function. You can only do so if that function is the only one that uses it. Your function is named `getData`, which implies that something else is going to be doing something with that data -- which means that it has to know what the structure looks like. But there's no firm rule. Do what makes sense for your application. (But a function that contains all the code that defines and uses a structure type is likely to be too big, and it's probably a candidate for splitting into smaller functions.)